# Salesforce: How to get Week Number in a Date field (checking week 53) either using apex code or formula

Tags: salesforce, formula, apex, week-number

Need to get the correct week number in a date field. Some date are having 53 weeks (you may refer here: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2026)

Apex:

`Datetime dt = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(2020, 12, 28); //Dec. 28, 2020
Integer week = Integer.valueOf(dt.formatGmt('w'));
System.debug('week number is ' + week);`

This returns:
`USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|week number is 1`

but should be week 53

Found this formula also:

`FLOOR((test_date__c-DATE(YEAR(test_date__c+(MOD(8-MOD(test_date__c-DATE(1900,1,7),7)+1,7)-3)),1,1)+MOD((MOD(DATE(YEAR(test_date__c+(MOD(8-MOD(test_date__c-DATE(1900,1,7),7)+1,7)-3)),1,1)-DATE(1900,1,7),7)+1)+1,7)-3)/7+1)`

Seems correct but sometimes it returns **0 or 53** so what I did is just set some condition that if 0 then set to 53 BUT I found out that this is wrong on this Date:
**December 29, 2025** it returns **Week 53** but should be ***Week 1.***

Answer (score 2):

This works every time.

```
FLOOR(
(DATEVALUE(Your_date_field) -
DATE(YEAR(DATEVALUE(Your_date_field) -
WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(Your_date_field)-1)+4),1,3)+

WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(DATEVALUE(Your_date_field) -
WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(Your_date_field)-1)+4),1,3))+5)/7
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula worked for me try this. hope you get the solution

```
MOD(FLOOR( ( Expected_Launch_Date__c - DATE(2006,01,01)-6)/7),52)+1
```

Comment: Hi Praveen,

I tried that but seems it returns wrong week number.

December 28, 2020 returns week 2 but should be Week 53

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

MOD( FLOOR ( (  DATEVALUE( FIELD ) - DATE(2012,01,01) ) / 7 ), 52)